# Get raw get parameters from jetty

Tags: java, http, get, embedded-jetty

I embedded jetty in this program i am writing and it gives me an error

```
WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8!
```

when it tries to decode the get statement, it says UTF-8 not supported to read it, is there any way i can get the get url like from ? to the end and let me do my own parsing? or is there a way to over write so it just gets the parameters even if not in UTF-8, i don't know what char-set they are so i can't change the char-set to get it.